# How do I extrapolate data from a NON-LINEAR (logarithmic) standard curve in Excel?

Tags: nonlinear-equations

I have made a standard curve. The X-axis is logarithmic. The y-axis is linear.
I have added a logarithmic trendline 
(y = -1.546ln(x) + 39.254; R² = 0.9906).
How can I re-arrange the equation to calculate an unknown X-axis value?

Comment: *from a known y-value

Comment: just copy the equation you got into excel cell and place in it instead of X - put the cell name that contains the X value you want

Answer (score 2):

$$y = -1.546 \ln(x) + 39.254$$
$$\frac{39.254 - y}{1.546} = \ln(x)$$
$$\exp\left(\frac{39.254 - y}{1.546}\right) = x$$

In excel this is `=EXP((39.254 - Y)/1.546)` where Y is the cell address containing the Y value.